# Указатель на безымянную локальную переменную

Tags: c++, указатели

Можно ли сделать так? Побьется ли указатель?

```
void foo()
{
    SomeType *pObj = nullptr;
    pObj = &(SomeType(arg1, arg2));
    ...
    // *pObj ?
}
```

Comment: Думаю, что нельзя. Насколько я помню, только ссылки продлевают жизнь временного объекта. Может, кто-то приведёт цитату из стандарта по этому поводу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нельзя. Продлевает срок жизни только константная lvalue-ссылка и rvalue-ссылка.
Вот так можно:

```
void foo()
{
    const SomeType& obj = SomeType(arg1, arg2);
    ...
    // obj !
}
```

и вот так:

```
void foo()
{
    SomeType&& obj = SomeType(arg1, arg2);
    ...
    // obj !
}
```

Доказательство вышесказанного можно найти в стандарте C++(12.2/5):

> There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the fullexpression
>   ....
>
> The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The
>   temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the
>   complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound
>   persists for the lifetime of the reference except...

Comment: Ссылку на стандарт найдёте?

Comment: @VladD
12.2.4 драфта C++11

Comment: @VladD, 12.2/5 стандарта

Comment: @ixSci: О, круто, плюсую!